# i try to make a bot but when i run kick command thats happend

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I ran my kick command and got this error below:

```js
(node:13176) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: message.guild.channels.find is not a function
        at Object.run (C:\Users\somna\Desktop\bot\commands\moderation\kick.js:11:51)
        at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\somna\Desktop\bot\index.js:48:17)
        at Client.emit (events.js:310:20)
        at MessageCreateAction.handle (C:\Users\somna\Desktop\bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageCreate.js:31:14)    
        at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (C:\Users\somna\Desktop\bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
        at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (C:\Users\somna\Desktop\bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:386:31)
        at WebSocketShard.onPacket (C:\Users\somna\Desktop\bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:436:22)   
        at WebSocketShard.onMessage (C:\Users\somna\Desktop\bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:293:10)  
        at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\somna\Desktop\bot\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:120:16)
        at WebSocket.emit (events.js:310:20)
```

Comment: Add your code, throwing an error and not showing code means you can almost never have your question answered.

Comment: If my answer solved your issue, then go ahead and accept it as the answer to this question so you can let others know what worked

Answer (score 2):

Despite you not including any code, from the error, I could tell that you're using discord.js v12 and have not used `.cache`

change `message.guild.channels.find()` to `message.guild.channels.cache.find()`.